# How I can do shape half circle in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am making app farm management system, and I want to make design for any pages such as Login, Register, Settings, etc...

I really don't how I can make it, but check this one I made a plan:

[Plan for Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf497.png)

I tried to create shape half circle and move in the corner, but It won't work.

I hope if you can help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#046500"/>
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#5BED00"
        android:centerColor="#00A800"
        android:endColor="#157300"
        android:angle="270" />
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="60dp"/>
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="70dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! what you have tried ? can you please post any code?

Comment: please edit your question and post the code

Comment: See the picture of the plan, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00046500"/>
            <size
                android:width="120dp"
                android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="30dp" android:start="-120dp"
        android:top="-30dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#046500"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#5BED00"
                android:centerColor="#00A800"
                android:endColor="#157300"
                android:angle="270" />
            <size
                android:width="120dp"
                android:height="70dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

output like this [image]